# ES6 extending classes and import dependencies

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, reactjs

I'm assuming this is a side effect of using babel with JSX, but if I have the following:

```
// classa.js
import React from 'react';
Class A extends React.Component {...}
export {A}

// classb.js
import {A} from './classa'
Class B extends A {
   render() {
      return <div>hello world</div>;
   }
}
export {B}
```

I have to include the import React from 'react'; in class B for this to work (even though it's already in class A).  If I wasn't using babel and could use es6 directly...would that still be the case?

Comment: It's not that the class itself needs the React namespace, it's because jsx will transpile `<div>` to `React.createElement('div')`. So the files that have any jsx also need to include React.

Comment: @azium: You should make that an answer

Comment: React devs say to avoid subclassing and favor composition :) https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/best-practices-for-extending-subclassing-components/1820